# How to say "let's" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

I wanna translate the following into Spanish.

> **Let's** make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. **Let's** all press "commit" button!

I've been searching around for a while but seems that there is no equivalent for `let's` in Spanish.
Some special cases like `let's go`, `let's make it happen`, `let's make love` have been asked on other forums but seems there is no special grammar like in English?

Comment: Related: [“Let's go” in Spanish](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14882/12637)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the present subjunctive in the first person plural form for the action intended.

- **Hagamos clic en el botón «commit»**
  <sup>Let's click on the button "commit"</sup>
- **Hablemos**
  <sup>Let's talk</sup>
- **Pensemos en algo...**
  <sup>Let's think about something...</sup>

Comment: Then is this translation true? For the English sentence `Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!` we should say `Vamos a hacer un sitio para teledetección y fotogrametría real. Vamos a hacer clic todos en el botón «commit»` in Spanish

Comment: it should be `hagamos un sitio [...]`

Answer (score 10):

I usually translate "let's" with the Spanish *vamos a*. Using the examples in [guifa's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18227/12637) (which is perfectly correct):

- ¡Vamos a hacer clic en el botón "commit"!
- ¡Vamos a hablar!
- ¡Vamos a pensar en algo!

A special case would be the translation of "let's go!":

- ¡Vamos!

Please note that this answer may be limited to some regions. At least I know that it is valid in Spain. In other regions, as commented below, you can use *vámonos*, *vayamos* or just stick to the subjunctive as pointed by guifa.

Also note the use of the exclamation marks, because if you don't write them, it seems that you are just saying "we're going to press the commit button" (*vamos a pulsar el botón commit*), as in response to the question "¿qué vais a hacer?".

Comment: Dear downvoter, I sincerely don't mind to be downvoted, but could you at least explain why my answer deserves such a fate so I can have a chance to improve it?

Comment: It's interesting to note that the form *vamos* in this case is actually subjunctive (cf. Portuguese *vá, vás, vá, **vamos**, vades, vão*), but has stuck around almost exclusively in Spanish in this command-ish form.

Comment: @guifa actually I'd swear I've seen it as 1st pers. pl. of the _imperative_ case in some grammar book.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo I wasn't, but the problem I see here is that _vamos a_ is either not valid in just _every_ context, or a regionalism mostly valid in Spain rather than in all of the Spanish-speaking world.

Comment: @rafael that's more of a terminological issue.  Traditional Spanish grammar only has three imperative forms for each verb (all affirmative): *tú*, *vos*, *vosotros* (the ones for *ir* are *ve*, *andá*, and *id*).  The other forms (negative, formal, and 1st person plural) are considered to be uses of the *subjuntivo exhortativo*, but functionally, they're commands, and so some grammars will —not at all incorrectly, since it's more of a "how you define them" thing— teach them as imperative.

Comment: Una alternativa, a ¡Vamos!, sería **¡Vámonos!**, término que aprendí mientras viví en Venezuela.

Comment: Then is this translation true? For the English sentence `Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!`, we should say `Vamos a hacer un sitio para teledetección y fotogrametría real. Vamos a hacer clic todos en el botón «commit»` in Spanish @Rafael (i didn't mention Carlos because he'll be notified automatically)

Comment: @David i didn't mention guifa because he'll be notified by commenting on his answer

Comment: @sepideh please note that I have improved my answer, so a proper translation should be the same you propose but adding exclamation marks. On the other hand, I really appreciate my answer being marked as the accepted one, but I sincerely think that [guifa's answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18227/12637) is better. I was just giving an alternative, but I would translate your sentences as "hagamos real un sitio web para teledetección y fotogrametría, ¡pulsemos todos el botón commit!"

Comment: In fact at first, I had translated based on guifa's answer as `• Hagamos un sitio para teledetección y fotogrametría real. Hagamos todas clic en el botón «commit»`, what do you think about this one? and what's that `¡` in the second verb of your suggestion in the previous comment? if it's an exclamation mark, they why don't we use it in the first verb, too? something like `¡hagamos`

Comment: @sepideh according to the Spanish rules, you can say "hagamos todas clic" if you are all women. Otherwise, use "hagamos todos". The rest seems OK. And the exclamation mark in the second verb is because I wanted to give emphasys only to the second part of the sentence. But you can put that mark at the start instead, or just get rid of them.